# Making Sympy's system of equations iterable

Tags: python, sympy, iterable, equation-solving

I am trying to figure out an efficient way for solving systems of equations in Sympy "automatically". Let me exemplify, this is a standard approach to formulating the code

```
n = 3  
y = sp.symbols('y1:{}'.format(n + 1))
TempDict1=(sp.solve([Dem_s[0],Dem_s[1]],(y[0],y[1])))
```

I want to make it iterable, so the system of equations update itself with regards to how many equations and variables exists in the lists of Dem_s and y respectively.

I have tried the following:

```
Templist=[]
for i in range(n-1):
    Templist.append(y[i])

TempDict1={}
for i in range(n-1):
    TempDict1=sp.solve([Dem_s[i]], (Templist))
```

However, this will not solve it. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first snippet would be better expressed as

```
n = 3  
y = sp.symbols('y1:{}'.format(n + 1))
TempDict1 = sp.solve(Dem_s, y)
```

If you have a tuple of variables `y`, there is no need to unpack and repack it with `(y[0], y[1])`. Passing `y` should do exactly what you want.

You didn't show how `Dem_s` is formed, but as long as it's a list or tuple of SymPy expressions, the above will work.